# jsp how to creat a log.txt file in openshift

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat7, openshift

I need to save something for every request in a log.txt file.

index.jsp in the below do that (which runs in localhost) correctly.

```
StringBuilder html =  new StringBuilder();
ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
        String file = context.getRealPath("/");
        html.append(html);
        file += "log.txt";
        System.out.println(file);
        html.append("<br/>\n____________________________________<br/>\n");//file path
        html.append(file.toString());//file path
        html.append("<br/>\n____________________________________<br/>\n");//file path

        FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
        filewriter.write(html.toString());
        filewriter.close();
```

But when i push my project in Openshift it return null as file path:
I create log.txt manually and set 777 for its permission near index.jsp but it is always empty!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the developer center [[1]](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/filesystem.html) you should use the `data` folder if you want to have persistent storage of your uploaded/dynamically created files. Or else they will be wiped every time you perform a git push.

Comment: Your right, But how to create files there ? I try to create file in /data but it has some error !!?? May I have any code about that ?